# List view problems

Tags: android, json

I have an json array with my database in it. I receive this array on my android app. By list view I receive the titles. When I click on one event I want to open a new activity with information about this event. "Datainicio" is my variable with information and "Titulo" is my variable with titles. How can I achieve this?

```
package com.eu.agendamarinhagrande;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.JSONParser;
import com.eu.agendamarinhagrande.R;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.text.Normalizer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    // JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> empresaList;


    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_empresas = "http://www.grifin.pt/projectoamg/Conexao.php";

    // JSON Node names


    private static final String TAG_TITULO = "Titulo";


    // products JSONArray
    String resultado = null;

    ListView lista;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Hashmap para el ListView
        empresaList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new Download().execute();

        // Cargar los productos en el Background Thread

        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        // ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        // actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }//fin onCreate

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }


    public class Download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String out = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url_all_empresas);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                out = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, HTTP.UTF_8);

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return out;
        }


        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsa = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String str = jsa.getString("Titulo");
                    String data = jsa.getString("Datainicio");
                    Log.e("TAG", str);
                    Log.e("TAG", data);


                    String s1 = Normalizer.normalize(str, Normalizer.Form.NFKD);
                    String regex = Pattern.quote("[\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}\\p{IsLm}\\p{IsSk}]+");

                    str = new String(s1.replaceAll(regex, "").getBytes("ascii"), "ascii");

                    list.add(str+"\n"+data);

                }

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

                // updating listview
                //setListAdapter(adapter);
                lista.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should google it before post question into Stack

Comment: Lol guy if i am asking on stack it's because i cant search or understand this on google

Comment: whats your problem in this code??

Comment: I am new on android , i dont know how i can click on one event  and open new activity with information about this event   and only this event

Comment: That is a **LOT** of code. Have a look at ["*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some tips on trimming your code down - this will help others to help you (and possibly avoid further downvoting).

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemOnclick Listener as like below to your listview

```
yourlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //Your intent goes here

           String yourvalue = yourarry.get(position).getyourvalue;

        }
    });
```

Comment: My problem is imagine i have url_all_empresas is my array json where i have titles information images etc .
what i need to do for take information about only the event i click  ?  one new activity?  can you show me in code ? i am new one android sorry

Comment: you can able to get listview with your items right??  Are you want to get any value when click the listview ???

Comment: Yes , imagine my list view have value1 and value2  when i click on value1 open new activity with information about value1 , and i  click on value2  information about value2 , the problem is i have this information on array url_all_empressas i dont know how to take this information automatic

Comment: check it out my updated answer, your arraylist.get(position) makes the trick